# Remapping Keys on Application

Tags: c#, ascii, keymapping

In my program, I want to be able to maybe input "E" on my keyboard and have it output on the textbox as a different letter, e.g. "F".

What's the most effective way to do this without clashes in sending keys?

```
    private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.E:
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                SendKeys.Send("F".ToLowerInvariant());
                break; 
            case Keys.F:
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                SendKeys.Send("E".ToLowerInvariant());
                break;            
        }
    }
```

I tried using the method above but it ends up clashing and it ends up sending a different letter instead.

Comment: Why not just `key = 'T'`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It is currently working like that but is there a way to actually output the set letter? I thought ascii would sort this problem out. If I was to type F, it would record it as T but still outputs F.

Comment: *What* exactly outputs `F`? Which event are you handling? How do you assign `key`? Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i've edited the post and tried a different method but no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `KeyPress` event for this, instead of `KeyDown`/`KeyUp` event.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper())
    {
        case "E":
            e.KeyChar = 'f';
            break;
        case "F":
            e.KeyChar = 'e';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to work with the LowerInvariant or the Upper? This way I don't have to create further cases for lower case letters